# Fastest Way to process data from DataTable to Excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel, datatable

I'm structuring and converting Data in a DataTable. Now I want to put the Data in an Excel File. As fast as possible.
I tried to fix the issue with Interop Com Objects. That took much too long.
Then I tried it with SQL commands like this:

```
        try
        {               
            tables = GetAllTables(conStrDest);

            con.ConnectionString =conStrDest;
            foreach (DataRow elem in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (elem[7] != "")
                {                      

                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [" + tables[0] + "] (LGNUM,LGTYP,LGPLA,LGBER) VALUES ('" + elem[2] + "','" + elem[4] + "','" + elem[7] + "','" + elem[4] + "')";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }               
        }
```

The Table has about 250.000 Rows and 7 Columns.
Processing The Data with SQL Statements takes > 24 hours.

Is there a faster Way? PS: I don't want to use a library for the issue.

Thank You.

Comment: Why not creating a CSV file instead of trying to insert every single record in the excel file?

Comment: Show what you tried with COM interop - I suspect you are looping and setting the values cell by cell.  If you put the data into an array and set the value of a range in one shot you'll probably get MUCH better results.  Any decent profiler would have shown you that the COM calls are where most of the time is spent.

Comment: this tiny piece of code is a honey pod for SQL injection!!

Comment: If you spreadsheets are in Open XML format (xlsx) you can use Microsoft's Open XML SDK to directly manipulate the contents without using any COM. Should be significantly faster. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

Comment: Sorry didn't see the PS about not using a library. I'm going to leave the previous comment for future readers. You could conceivably write your own methods to manipulate an Open XML format document. They are essentially a zip file with specifically formatted internal structure containing xml files that represent the data, format, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your fast help.
@DStanley
I tried that too, but didn't doudn a way to get the Data from DataTable to 2D Array. 

Is CSV that much easier / faster? I think there will be the Same problem, right?